# Idiom or expression for describing a situation in which you cannot easily reject a request

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose someone (like a boss, friend, cousin,.., to whom you can not say "no" easily) has a personal request for you which you find difficult to decline, but you cannot bring yourself to say no, because you feel embarrassed or too shy to say no (i.e. you do not feel free to say no), or just simply don't like them to feel offended or hurt.
What is the expression or idiom that would convey this meaning: **"to accept a request in this situation, unwillingly but under your own moral pressure or just out of shyness"**.

I have found this idiom: ["to put somebody on the spot"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-sb-on-the-spot), can I use it in this situation?

For example:

> My mother-in-law asked me to accompany her to the market, and I was actually put on the spot by her request so I went shopping with her despite having a severe headache.

Comment: The desired term would likely depend on your relationship to the person making the request - different for the boss than for the friend, and the cousin is family, so probably different internal reactions for each, resulting in different appropriate terms.

Comment: You could feel a duty, an obligation, a debt, a responsibility... lots of words cover what you asked.

Comment: This is called “being *pressured into it [against their (will/better judgement)]” if the asker knows that they don’t really want to do it but also knows they won’t say ‘no” and asks anyway.

Comment: yes, it is exactly this case! @Jim!, so how about " I didn't like to accept her request, but I said yes only due to being  pressured into it"

Comment: "but I could not easily refuse."  Implies struggle with trying to refuse.

Comment: Similarly, you're too [accommodating, amenable, etc], when "too" is attached to an otherwise positive adjective, it implies the person is accommodating *to a fault* (another idiom).  To the point where it creates trouble.

Comment: Yes. "Accommodating to a fault" could mean that.  "Unwilling" is too strong if you are not actually "pressured [forced, cajoled] into it."  That would be making the decision *under duress*, pressure from someone else.  If it's your *own* character that causes you to decide to accommodate the request despite the consequences for yourself, I'd call that "accommodating to a fault" or "too accommodating."

Comment: I call this *being taken advantage of*...

Comment: @Tim Ward, thanks for your comment. Yes, this is being taken advantage , but I don't want to focus  on this aspect, I want to know an English equivalent to a Farsi idiom that means " to accept a request unwillingly especially out of shyness". :)

Comment: Thanks, @ab2. I got it. Happy to learn its meaning and its usage. But I have also found " to put somebody on the spot", what is your idea?

Comment: Yes, they are putting you on the spot.  That is a good one.  And they are probably doing it deliberately.  Being put on the spot is the consequence of being too nice for your own good.

Comment: @Soudabeh, yes, being "put on the spot" would work. But that's also an expression that's used when someone might do something that could embarrass/shame you, as in asking you a question that you don't know the answer to, in front of your friends. But the bottom line is that it makes you uncomfortable.

Comment: I imagine in previous centuries, when in Western cultures propriety and culture dominated social interaction, there may have been a more colorful way of saying this, perhaps even with a focus on the shyness or desire of the person being asked not to hurt the one asking. But I'm afraid I can't think of anything that means quite what "put on the spot" means...

Comment: Also, in some circumstances, you could use the expression "between a rock and a hard place" with certain requests.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use the word *diffident* when someone is acquiescing to another's authority. The word connotes not just "simple" shyness, but also a lack of self-confidence and assertiveness.

Definition: (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diffident)

> diffident
>   adjective
>   1. lacking confidence in one's own ability, worth, or fitness; timid; shy.

Another option would be *timid*. It's a fairly common word and I don't think I need to define it here.

To more directly put across the point of submission to authority, you can consider *submissive*.

Definition: (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/submissive)

> submissive
>   adjective
>   1. inclined or ready to submit or yield to the authority of another; unresistingly or humbly obedient:
>   submissive servants.
>   2. marked by or indicating submission or an instance of yielding to the authority of another: a submissive reply.

*Obedient* is another (more positive) option. Again, a word in common usage, and I won't be defining it here (it's easy to look up).

The most negative options, generally used critically, are *pushover* and *doormat*. They are idiomatic nouns that describe a person who seriously lacks self-assertiveness and may be defined as follows:

*Doormat* (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doormat):

> doormat
>
> 2. Slang One who submits meekly to domination or mistreatment by others.

*Pushover* (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pushover)

> push·o·ver
>
> 1. One that is easily defeated or taken advantage of.

In the same vein as the above two, there is another idiom, which I believe is peculiar to the US: *milquetoast*.

*Milquetoast* (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/milquetoast)

> milquetoast

noun, (sometimes initial capital letter)

> 1. a very timid, unassertive, spineless person, especially one who is easily dominated or intimidated:
>      a milquetoast who's afraid to ask for a raise.

And, as included in the definition of that word *spineless* is another negative adjective for someone lacking self-assertiveness. Again, it's a highly critical word. Given that the spine supports your body in an upright posture, I believe you should be able to see how the metaphorical meaning comes about.

Comment: Plus one for *acquiesce*. Put *acquiescent* in front of any of your words and now we have an idiom.

Comment: Pushover is a good one.  Or "pressured".  You could feel pressured to go shopping with your mother-in-law.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, *feel **obligated***.

> obligated: caused by law or conscience to follow a certain course.

[WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obligated)

Answer (score 2):

For an idiomatic phrase, your question itself contains a very good one.  You probably say 'yes' in these situations simply because you are one of the many people who “[have a hard time saying ‘no’](https://books.google.com/books?id=jCVACgAAQBAJ&pg=PA637&dq=%22hard+time+saying+no%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiojLarnb7KAhXKJiYKHR1GAKYQ6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=%22hard%20time%20saying%20no%22&f=false)” or similarly one who has “[trouble saying ‘no’](https://books.google.com/books?id=mkyhA1glBakC&pg=PA9&dq=%22trouble+saying+no%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGnuPmn77KAhVFeSYKHaG6BjoQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22trouble%20saying%20no%22&f=false).”
(examples from ‘Health and Wellness’ By Gordon Edlin et als and  ‘How to Say No...and Live to Tell About It: A Woman's Guide to Guilt-Free Decisions’ By Mary M. Byers, respectively, via Google Books)

Since you’ve already used this phrase in your question, however, you are obviously looking for something else, and another candidate for you to consider is “You have trouble saying ‘no’ because you are perhaps a “[people pleaser](http://kalimunro.com/wp/articles-info/emotions-and-feelings/people-pleasing).” (from ‘kalimunro[dot]com’)

“[People pleaser](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/shrink/201210/are-you-people-pleaser)”:

“A People Pleaser is one of the nicest and most helpful people you know. They never say “no.”  You can always count on them for a favor.  In fact, they spend a great deal of time doing things for other people.” (from ‘Psychology Today’)

As for a single word, ‘PsychCentral’ even hyphenates “[People-pleaser](http://psychcentral.com/lib/are-you-a-people-pleaser/).”

Please note that “people[-]pleaser” would work best in contexts involving friends and family, for in cases involving bosses (and even co-workers), the reason might be better described as your being “**afraid** of the [**negative**] consequences [of saying ‘no’].”

And, of course, there’s the possibility, regardless of the context, that the nature of the people to whom you find yourself most often saying ‘yes’ explains the phenomenon:

“I have trouble saying ‘no’ because most of my bosses/friends/family/co-workers **don't easily take no for an answer** [and I’m not assertive enough to deal with their persistence].”

(cf: reasons 2 and 3 (behind #1, which involves “pleasing everyone”) listed in Sonali Ila Ekka, Aspiring Dog Owner’s answer to [this question](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-have-a-hard-time-saying-no) posted on ‘Quora’)

Answer (score 1):

"I could never refuse the Boss, I'm far too **inhibited**"

> [**inhibited**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=inhibited+definition&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: unable to act in a relaxed and natural way because of self-consciousness or mental restraint.
>
> **synonyms**: shy, reticent, reserved, self-conscious, diffident, bashful, coy

(Google)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Little Eva, +1 _if I accept my friend's request for accompanying her in shopping, and I accept only out of being shy to say "no, I can't come with you now", shall I use "I was too far inhibited to say no to her"? :)

Comment: I'd say that "inhibited" would be less precise under those circumstances - which are personal, as opposed to professional - the difficulty in refusing a friend's request is due to not wishing to "hurt" or "offend" your friend's feelings. Maybe you are then, too "sensitive" or "sympathetic."

Comment: how about "overly obliging"?

Comment: Especially considering the OP as edited, I think your suggestion of "obliging" or "obligated" is fitting. Why don't you submit this, @ab2, with definition/citation/link, included?

Comment: Little Eva: Because I am jet-lagged.  ab2

Comment: Then just relax, @ab2. We got it from here. :-)

Comment: Certainly. Sometimes I just don't feel like doing something, but I feel an obligation that rouses me to the task.

Answer (score 1):

You are ***too nice for your own good***

From [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/collections/201203/too-nice-your-own-good)

> Are you agreeable, accommodating and saintly to a fault?  Being too
>   nice for your own good can take a toll on you.  The key: Knowing when
>   to curtail kindness.

Just two items from the Table of Contents of the online issue:

> The Perils of Being Too Nice;
>    7 Ways to Say No and Keep Good
>   Relations....how to set boundaries without feeling guilty.

When you google "too nice for your own good", you will find many articles, far too many to link here, and even a book [Too Nice for Your Own Good](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=too+nice+for+your+own+good)

It is a very popular pop-psychology topic.

As for **put on the spot**, yes you can use it in the way you illustrated. People who are *too nice for their own good* are frequently *put on the spot* or just feel put on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

**soft touch** (noun)

> a person who is easily imposed on or taken advantage of
>
> *> the kindly old woman was a soft touch for any con man with a hard-luck story*

(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soft%20touch)

Answer (score 1):

When someone unwilingly do something, he acts **against his wishes**.

> Example: *Let me point out that our group forces no one to participate
>   against his wishes*.